# Forbidden You don't have permission to access index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, categories, magento-1.9

I am facing this problem when I clicked on manage categories URL from admin panel of magento 1.9 ce. It gives the error mentioned below:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /metrosofa/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/f4cd10e9a0094f36b1358be24bd2a392/
>   on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered
>   while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: The admin panel of what? What are you talking about? Please add a [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to indicate which tool and/or language you're using, and, if you wrote any of this code whatsoever yourself, please include [an minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: I am really Sorry I forget to tag, actually this is magento site error, I am using 1.9 version of magento c.e and when i click on manage categories page it give the above error. I am a little new and unable to solve this problem. Highly appreciated upon help. Thank you